# Stdout to file from which is reading content

Tags: file, bash, io, redirect, io-redirection

When I want to modify files using Bash, I usually redirect stdout to another file and then remove the original. Is there a faster way?

For example:

```
cut -d':' -f2 FILE > FILE
```

This makes my source file empty (it empty the file before writing and then starts reading)

All I can do is:

```
cut -d':' -f2 FILE > FILE2
rm -f FILE
mv FILE2 FILE
```

Is there a way to redirect the (modified) output to the original file in just one step?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you install [Colin Watson's `sponge` utility](http://riva.ucam.org/~cjwatson/blog/2006-02-06-sponge.html) (the link on Colin's blog seems to be dead, but you can get it as part of [Joey Hess' moreutils package](http://kitenet.net/~joey/code/moreutils/)), you can use it to "soak up" the output before dumping it back into the file:

```
cat FILE | cut -d':' -f2 | sponge FILE
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll try it soon, probably it is exactly what i was looking for.

Comment: doing `cat .zsh_history | sponge > .zsh_history` erased everything. `sponge` is supposed to support stdout when no file is specified, but in this case seems to have malfunctioned. Any ideas people?

Comment: @TonyH The problem is that you used `sponge > .zsh_history` instead of `sponge .zsh_history`. The `>` means that the shell does the redirect into the output file, and the shell *always* deletes the file's contents before even starting the command (`sponge` in this case). If you pass the filename as an argument to `sponge` instead, it waits until it's done reading everything from its input pipe, *then* deletes the old contents and writes out the new contents.

Comment: Thanks for explaining the shell's responsibility there. I can see where sponge's stdout support could be useful as part of a longer pipe.

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid I don't have an answer for you in bash, but it's very easy in zsh:

```
cut -d':' -f2 =(cat FILE) > FILE
```

The `=(...)` construct creates a temporary file containing the output of the program mentioned which is removed after the command containing it is finished.

Comment: Thank you anyway. However is there a way to do this with something like "shopt"?

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid there is no convenient general way of doing that in bash.   The problem is that before running any commands, bash opens the `FILE` for output, truncating it, so when `cat` opens the file, all it sees is the new, empty file.  `sed` has a `-i` option to do the replacement inline (for which it actually uses a temporary file), and `zsh` has `=(...)`, as mentioned in other answers, and `sort` manually checks whether the input and output files match (when using `-o`, as I mentioned, using the shell redirect will wipe the file before the program ever sees it), but `cut` and many other utilities don't.  You have to use a temporary file for those.